# Is it possible to set the valid property of a Control?

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

Given a control titleCtrl, is there a way to set its valid property?

I tried

#### .dart

```
titleCtrl.valid = false;
```

but it throws an error. Getting the valid state is no problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `valid` property of a `Control` is a read only property. You cannot assign the value. The correct way to have something become invalid is to create a custom validator

Here is the example code snippet from the Angular2 TypeScript documentation

```
class CustomValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(c: Control): {[key: string]: any} {
    return {"custom": true};
  }
}
```

Your validations do not need to be in a separate class though, when you create a `ControlGroup` using `FormBuilder` you can set custom validations on the individual controls.

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent{
  myForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
        myField: ['', Validators.compose([this.customValidation.bind(this)])],
    });
  }

  customValidation(control: Control){
    if(/* some condition */){
      return {'myValidatorKey': true};
    }
  }
}
```

This technique can be used to validate any field including fields that are dependent on the values of other fields and any other logic.

Sadly the Angular2 team hasn't released any documentation on [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart) usage so I cannot provide examples in [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart), however I have attempted to remove as much typescript specific noise to help make the answer as generic as possible.

Comment: Does the `control: Control` param in `customValidation` method refers to `myField`? If so `customValidation` sets the validity of `myField` to true and similarly could `return {`myValidatorKey`: false };` makes `myField valid` property false?

Comment: Not quite. The `myValidatorKey` is the key of the error, and setting this to `true` means that the error has occurred, which in turn makes `.valid === false`.  Think of this more as *"The myValidatorKey error is present"*

Comment: Great and thanks. The comment gives me much clarity.

Comment: Why I ask the question in the first place is because I don't want to see invalid controls in my form at initialization. To prevent this, I actually invalidate the control base on the empty string and pristine property. However, when this is done the submit button is displayed initially. I was thinking that if I could display the submit button when all the controls became valid instead. What is your thoughts on the best way do this, given your solution above.